# Scala App won't compile in ScalaIDE 4.2 with -Ydelambdafy:method -Ybackend:GenBCode

Tags: eclipse, scala, sbt, scala-ide, scala-2.11

I have a Scala app that compiles and runs fine with sbt 0.13.9 but with the same options it won't compile in ScalaIDE (Eclipse). I am using Scala 2.11.7 and jdk8_60 with the options `-Ydelambdafy:method -Ybackend:GenBCode`. If I remove the options it will compile. This is not really urgent for me but if it is a bug it would be nice to find someone who could figure out what is wrong so it could get recorded.

Thanks.

```
object TestDataApp extends App {

  val outputDir = "src/main/scala"

  def writeFile(fileName: String, contents: String) {
    import java.nio.file._
    val p  = Paths.get(outputDir, fileName)
    Files.write(p, contents.getBytes)
  }

  def createLines(strs: IndexedSeq[String]) = {
    strs.mkString("\n")
  }

  def createUsersString() = {
    val nums = 1 to 50000            
    val strs = nums.map("ta_" + _.toString)
    createLines("userId" +: strs)
  }

  def createActorsString(actors: List[String]) = {

    def createActorString(actor: String) = {
      val searches = actor.scanLeft("")((a,b) => a + b).tail
      createLines(searches)
    }

    // accumulater acc is a StringBuilder - term is header
    val initSb = new StringBuilder("term\n" + createActorString(actors.head))
    val sb = actors.tail.foldLeft(initSb)((acc, e) => acc.append("\n").append(createActorString(e)))
    sb.toString()
  }

  def readActorList(fileName: String): List[String] = {
    import scala.io.{Source, Codec}
    import java.io.InputStream
    val stream = getClass.getResourceAsStream(fileName)
    val lines = Source.fromInputStream(stream)(Codec.UTF8).getLines
    lines.map(line => line.split("\\t").head).toList
  }

  // write the files
  println("Writing files...")
  writeFile("userId.txt", createUsersString())
  val actors = readActorList("input.txt")
  writeFile("term.txt", createActorsString(actors))
  println("Done.")
}
```

The input.txt file is tab delimited and looks like this.

```
Alex Colls  124
Larry Jacobs    65
Graham Falk 64
Pere Clos   60
Hunter Parrish  41
```

Jvm targets of 1.6 and 1.7 and 1.8 will not work. Sbt does with these options: `scalacOptions ++= Seq("-deprecation", "-feature", "-Ydelambdafy:method", "-Ybackend:GenBCode")`
Here are the errors from the IDE.

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Couldn't create file for class TestDataApp$lambda$$readActorList$1 null TestDataApp.scala   /sc-test/src/main/scala line 3  Scala Problem

Couldn't create file for class TestDataApp$lambda$$sb$1 null    TestDataApp.scala   /sc-test/src/main/scala line 3  Scala Problem

Couldn't create file for class TestDataApp$lambda$$searches$1 null  TestDataApp.scala   /sc-test/src/main/scala line 3  Scala Problem

Couldn't create file for class TestDataApp$lambda$$strs$1 null  TestDataApp.scala   /sc-test/src/main/scala line 3  Scala Problem

Error in Scala compiler: assertion failed:    Precisely this override requires its invoker to hand out a non-null AbstractFile.      while compiling: C:\Users\erichardson\workspaces\scala\sc-test\src\main\scala\TestDataApp.scala         during phase: jvm      library version: version 2.11.7     compiler version: version 2.11.7   reconstructed args: -Ydelambdafy:method -deprecation -classpath C:\Users\erichardson\workspaces\scala\sc-test\bin;C:\Users\erichardson\eclipse-scala-ide-4.1.1\plugins\org.scala-lang.scala-reflect_2.11.7.v20150622-112736-1fbce4612c.jar;C:\Users\erichardson\eclipse-scala-ide-4.1.1\plugins\org.scala-lang.scala-actors_2.11.7.v20150622-112736-1fbce4612c.jar -Ybackend:GenBCode -javabootclasspath C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_60\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_60\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_60\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_60\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_60\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_60\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_60\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_60\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_60\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_60\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_60\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_60\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_60\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_60\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_60\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_60\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_60\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_60\lib\ext\zipfs.jar -javaextdirs   -target:jvm-1.7 -bootclasspath C:\Users\erichardson\eclipse-scala-ide-4.1.1\plugins\org.scala-lang.scala-library_2.11.7.v20150622-112736-1fbce4612c.jar    last tree to typer: TypeTree(class String)        tree position: line 26 of C:\Users\erichardson\workspaces\scala\sc-test\src\main\scala\TestDataApp.scala             tree tpe: String               symbol: final class String in package lang    symbol definition: final class String extends Serializable with Comparable with CharSequence (a ClassSymbol)       symbol package: java.lang        symbol owners: class String            call site: constructor TestDataApp$delayedInit$body in class TestDataApp$delayedInit$body in package <empty>  == Source file context for tree position ==      23      24     def createActorString(actor: String) = {     25       val searches = actor.scanLeft("")((a,b) => a + b).tail     26       createLines(searches)     27     }     28      29     // accumulater acc is a StringBuilder - term is header   sc-test     Unknown Scala Problem

SBT builder crashed while compiling. The error message is 'assertion failed:    Precisely this override requires its invoker to hand out a non-null AbstractFile.      while compiling: C:\Users\erichardson\workspaces\scala\sc-test\src\main\scala\TestDataApp.scala         during phase: jvm      library version: version 2.11.7     compiler version: version 2.11.7   reconstructed args: -Ydelambdafy:method -deprecation -classpath C:\Users\erichardson\workspaces\scala\sc-test\bin;C:\Users\erichardson\eclipse-scala-ide-4.1.1\plugins\org.scala-lang.scala-reflect_2.11.7.v20150622-112736-1fbce4612c.jar;C:\Users\erichardson\eclipse-scala-ide-4.1.1\plugins\org.scala-lang.scala-actors_2.11.7.v20150622-112736-1fbce4612c.jar -Ybackend:GenBCode -javabootclasspath C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_60\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_60\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_60\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_60\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_60\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_60\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_60\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_60\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_60\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_60\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_60\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_60\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_60\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_60\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_60\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_60\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_60\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_60\lib\ext\zipfs.jar -javaextdirs   -target:jvm-1.7 -bootclasspath C:\Users\erichardson\eclipse-scala-ide-4.1.1\plugins\org.scala-lang.scala-library_2.11.7.v20150622-112736-1fbce4612c.jar    last tree to typer: TypeTree(class String)        tree position: line 26 of C:\Users\erichardson\workspaces\scala\sc-test\src\main\scala\TestDataApp.scala             tree tpe: String               symbol: final class String in package lang    symbol definition: final class String extends Serializable with Comparable with CharSequence (a ClassSymbol)       symbol package: java.lang        symbol owners: class String            call site: constructor TestDataApp$delayedInit$body in class TestDataApp$delayedInit$body in package <empty>  == Source file context for tree position ==      23      24     def createActorString(actor: String) = {     25       val searches = actor.scanLeft("")((a,b) => a + b).tail     26       createLines(searches)     27     }     28      29     // accumulater acc is a StringBuilder - term is header'. Check Error Log for details.  sc-test     Unknown Scala Problem

sc-test's tests not built due to errors in dependent scope(s) main  sc-test     Unknown Scala Problem
```